# Is glCopyTexture2d slower than using framebuffer object

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am using glCopyTexture2d to create a texture from screen content in a iphone game. Its simple, I wonder if using frame buffer (render to texture) for the same is has any performance gain. However (render to texture) is not straight forward for me. Theoretically  glCopyTexture2d is a VRAM to VRAM copy. Have any body experienced performance gain using 'render to texture' in compare to glCopyTexture2d.

Answer (score 1):

render to texture using FBOs should be faster than `glCopyTexImage2D`, as directly rendering to the texture completely prevents any copy (be it only VRAM to VRAM, which is still a copy of pretty much data). But you should try out yourself if it gives a real benefit for your application. [This site](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) has a nice introduction to FBOs together with a simple render to texture tutorial. If you have FBO support, you should really give it a try, it might be worth it.

And by the way, using `glCopyTexSubImage2D` should even be faster than `glCopyTexImage2D` (assuming an already existing texture of correct size), as this way the texture memory doesn't get allocated completely new.